# Is there a problem with this mysql update in a php for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this php code to update a table, but nothing is updating?

```
if(isset($Submit))
{
    include('connect_mysql.php');
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE $table SET cost='{$cost[$i]}', net=('{$bypiece[$i]}' + '{$cost[$i]}') WHERE serial='{$serial[$i]}'";
        $result = mysql_query($dbcon, $sql);
    }
}

if($result)
{
    header("location:admin-index.php#office.php");
    mysql_close();
}
```

It seems like it should work, and i have no reason why it wouldn't.
My variables are defined, and when i echo them out with an else statement everything seems to be alright. Yet the data isn't being updated, and the header isn't redirecting.
Can anyone help me find a working solution?

Comment: Have you tired echoing out $sql, and testing if it's valid? What about mysql_error(), does that give you anything?

Comment: Which mysql error description do you get? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: You don't initialize `$result` if `$Submit` is not set. Then you run multiple queries w/o even checking if they worked or not. E.g. if the last fails, you will not be noticed about anything and there will be no redirect.

Comment: I don't see where $count is being set.  Is it set in your included file?

Comment: I don't get any sql_error, even with or die(mysql_error()) after ($dbcon, $sql);.  When i echo $sql after the if($result), i don't get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea when debugging is turn on error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Also see if you have any errors in your sql statement by changing

```
$result=mysql_query($dbcon, $sql);
```

to

```
$result=mysql_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you, i've never thought of putting error reporting on a page. This led me to my errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
net=('{$bypiece[$i]}' + '{$cost[$i]}')
```

To:

```
net=({$bypiece[$i]} + {$cost[$i]})
```

You should also have some error checking with the query.

```
 if(isset($Submit)){ 
 include('connect_mysql.php'); 
 $count=20;
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
  $sql="UPDATE $table SET cost='{$cost[$i]}', net=({$bypiece[$i]} + {$cost[$i]}) WHERE serial='{$serial[$i]}'"; 
  $result=mysql_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mylsql_error());
 } 
 if($result){ 
  header("location:admin-index.php#office.php"); 
  mysql_close(); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is $count set to? Your code would go nowhere in the state that it is in right now since $count isn't set to anything.

Comment: $count = mysql_num_rows($result2);